# Как правильно называется такой класс: Model или DTO?

Tags: java, android

```
public class User {

    private String first, last, city;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String first, String last, String city) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Смотря для чего он используется.

Comment: А может POJO? )

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а разве бывают разные задачи? Не подскажите, где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: Если класс используется для моделирования данных, хранящихся в БД, то он является _моделью_. Если класс используется для передачи данных между слоями приложения, то его экземпляры являются **D**ata **T**ransfer **O**bject.

Comment: вот, вот.. структурно это POJO, а использовать его можно в качестве DTO или Model